# Excel add-in with logging class: How to react to VBA state loss?

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

#### The setup

I'm developing and maintaining an Excel add-in that comes with its own tab of controls within Excel's Ribbon UI. I've come across the problem of state loss before (meaning loss of all variables with global scope, static variables, etc, which of course includes my reference to the RibbonUI). With regards to the ribbon reference I've "solved" the problem by including a "Reset Ribbon" button that restores the reference from a persistently stored pointer and then invalidates the ribbon. Although certainly not the most elegant, this part works just fine.

However, after the introduction of a logging class, the state loss issue haunts me once again. The logger is instantiated in ThisWorkbook's module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set LogToFile = SingletonFactory.getToFileLogger
End Sub
```

and is then put to work, for example, as follows:

```
Private Sub buttonReloadObjects_onAction(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)
    LogToFile.trace "Event firing: buttonReloadObjects_onAction"
    ' more stuff happening...
    invalidateRibbon ' restores ribbon object and invalidates it
End Sub
```

The logger is instantiated when the add-in is loaded so that I have the freedom to log whatever I want within the confines of my add-in's code. It has several logging levels like trace/debug/error/... and a couple of other methods. Usually it works just fine - until the state loss hits (usually caused by an unrelated error, followed by clicking "End").

#### State loss

At this point the VBA environment forgets about the very existence of my `LogToFile` object and nothing works any more, because every click on the ribbon controls will trigger a `runtime error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set` pointing to whatever line is the first to contain a reference to `LogToFile`.

#### A solution?

Now, short of doing crazy workarounds like placing

```
if not isObject(LogToFile) then
    Set LogToFile = SingletonFactory.getToFileLogger
end if
LogToFile.trace "Message"
```

before *any* occurrence of `LogToFile`, the only real "solution" I was able to come up with is to wrap all my logger calls in functions (residing in a standard module) and call these functions any time I want to send something to the log. This way I could catch the missing object reference right before the object is needed and I avoid calling methods of uninstantiated objects.
However, after having everything neatly encapsulated in class modules, it strikes me as odd, maybe even wrong(?), going down this route.

---

So, is there a "proper" solution to the problem of a lost logger instance? Or is my suggested approach already as proper as it can get?

---

Note: This problem is of course not specific to logging classes. It affects all global variables, most notably my ApplicationEventClass. The issue just happens to be the most glaring with the logger due to its frequent usage around all entry points to the code.

Comment: You only need one function that either returns the original variable or resets it. If you call that function `LogToFile` you don't need to change any of the other code.

Comment: Interesting thought. But can I then still use the logging methods like `LogToFile.warn "Warning message"`?

Comment: Yes. `LogToFile` will return the correct object so you can call the methods just as you did before. You won't need the `workbook_open` code any more.

Comment: Wow, just experimented with that concept for a bit. That is really nifty! (Also a bit confusing at the first glance, but comparing it to the usage of functions with a numerical return value, it's basically just the equivalent with objects.) Would you mind posting this as an answer? Otherwise I can try to write something up. One last question: Are there any downsides to this technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one function that either returns the original variable or resets it. If you call that function `LogToFile` you don't need to change any of the other code other than removing the `Workbook_Open` code which is then superfluous. So:

```
Function LogToFile() As WhateverVariableType
Static temp as WhateverVariableType
If temp is Nothing then Set temp = SingletonFactory.getToFileLogger
Set LogToFile = temp
End Function
```

This way you will also still benefit from Intellisense when writing the code.

Note: you may not actually need the temp variable - it depends on whether there are settings that you want persisted. If there are, you may want to reset them in the function too.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually had something similar to your example function already in my `SingletonFactory` module. The puzzle piece missing for me was that I could directly replace any occurrence of my logger variable with a function returning the logger type and *still* access all of the logger's public properties and methods.